# What do these terms mean in MIPS?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, mips32

I'm just starting to learn about MIPS and such on my own. I've tried looking on other forums but nothing was mentioned.

What do branches mean in the MIPS context?

Answer (score 0):

`branch` or `jump` instructions are instructions that (often conditionally) go to an instruction other than the one immediately following the `branch`/`jump` instruction.  This is how 'control flow' is handled at the assembly level.